# Long Table with Long Text and Multicolumns

Tags: longtable, longtabu

I want to create a long table with a long text.

The minimal working example is given below:

```
     \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
     \usepackage{authblk}
     \usepackage{titlesec}
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
     \usepackage{times}
     \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
     \usepackage[english]{babel}
     \usepackage{amsthm}
     \usepackage{amsmath}
     \usepackage{mathptmx}
     \usepackage{float}
     \usepackage{url}
     \usepackage[final]{graphicx}
     \usepackage{natbib}
     \setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
     %page margins
     \usepackage{geometry}
     \geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm }
     \setlength\parindent{24pt}
     %produces line numbers
     \usepackage{textcomp}
     \usepackage{textgreek}
     \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
     \usepackage{libertineRoman}
     %line spacing
     \usepackage{setspace}
     \onehalfspacing
     \usepackage{titlesec}
     \usepackage{caption}% <-- added
     \usepackage{tabulary}
     \usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
     \usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable,tabularx}
     \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}% <-- added
     \usepackage{caption}% <-- added
     \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{7in}
     \usepackage{ltablex}% <-- added
     \usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added
     \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}
     \usepackage{pdflscape}
     \usepackage{amssymb}
     \begin{document}
     \section{introduction}
     Introduction text is given here.
     \begin{landscape}
         \begin{longtable} 
    \caption{Structure}
          \label{tab:str}\\
            \toprule
         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Main 1}} &       & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Main 2}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Main 3}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Main 4}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Main 5}} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Main 6}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Main 7}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{5-8}\cmidrule{10-10}\cmidrule{12-12}\cmidrule{14-14}\cmidrule{16-17}\cmidrule{19-19}     
              & Text 1a  &       &  Text2a  & Text2b & Text2c & Text 2d &       & Text 3a &       & Text4a &       & Text5a  &       & Text 6a & Text 6b &       & Text6b \\   
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{19}{c}%
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}\\
    \toprule
         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Main 1}} &       & \multicolumn{4}{c}        {\textbf{Main 2}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Main 3}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Main 4}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Main 5}} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Main 6}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Main 7}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{5-8}\cmidrule{10-10}\cmidrule{12-12}\cmidrule{14-14}\cmidrule{16-17}\cmidrule{19-19}     
              & Text 1a  &       &  Text2a  & Text2b & Text2c & Text 2d &       & Text 3a &       & Text4a &       & Text5a  &       & Text 6a & Text 6b &       & Text6b \\   
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{19}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
     %%%%%% Main contents of Table Starts here %%%%%%%%%%%%
         \multicolumn{19}{l}{\textbf{Structure }} \\
         \midrule
         Issuer & Licensed UCI  & Licensed UCI  &       & Specialised Credit Institution  & Specialised Credit Institution  & Specialised Credit Institution  & Specialised Credit Institution  &       & Licensed UCI  &       & UCI   &       & Licensed UCI  &       & UCI, Specialised Credit Institution  & UCI, Specialised Credit Institution  &       & UCI, Specialised Credit Institution  \\
         Recourse to credit institution  & Yes, direct  & Yes, direct  &       & Yes, direct  & Yes, direct  & Yes, direct  & Yes, direct  &       & Yes, direct  &       & Yes, direct  &       & Yes, direct  &       & Yes, direct  & Yes, direct  &       & Yes, direct  \\
         Owner of cover assets & Credit Institution acting as fiduciary  & Credit Institution acting as fiduciary  &       & Credit Institution, pledged to the issuer   & Credit Institution, pledged to the issuer   & The issuer directly  & Credit Institution, pledged to the issuer   &       & The issuer directly  &       & SPE which guarantees the CBs &       & SPE which guarantees the CBs &       & The issuer directly  & The issuer directly  &       & The issuer directly  \\
         Issuer is originator of assets & Flexible  & Flexible  &       & No    & No    & Flexible  & No    &       & Yes   &       & Yes   &       & Flexible  &       & Yes   & Yes   &       & Yes \\
         \midrule
         \multicolumn{19}{l}{\textbf{Framework }} \\
         \midrule
         Special legilsation  & Yes   & Yes   &       & Yes   & No    & Yes   & Yes   &       & Yes   &       & Yes   &       & Yes   &       & Yes   & Yes   &       & Yes \\
         Legal framework for the bankcruptcy of issuer & Special legal framework superseding general insolvency law  & Special legal framework superseding general insolvency law  &       & Special legal framework superseding general insolvency law  & General insolvency law & Special legal framework superseding general insolvency law  & Special legal framework superseding general insolvency law  &       & Special legal framework superseding general insolvency law  &       & Special legal framework superseding general insolvency law  &       & General insolvency law &       & Special legal framework superseding general insolvency law  & Special legal framework superseding general insolvency law  &       & Special legal framework superseding general insolvency law  \\
         \midrule
         \multicolumn{19}{l}{\textbf{Assets  }} \\
         \midrule
         Types of assets & Public Sector loans
     Mortgage loans
     Loans to credit institutions & Public Sector loans
     Mortgage loans
     Loans to credit institutions &       & Mortgage Loans & Mortgage Loans & Public Sector loans
     Mortgage loans
     Loans to credit institutions
     Senior MBS & Mortgage loans
     Senior MBS &       & Public Sector loans
     Mortgage loans
     Loans to credit institutions
     Ship loans
     Aircraft loans  &       & Public Sector loans
     Mortgage loans
     Senior MBS &       & Public Sector loans
     Mortgage loans
     Loans to credit institutions
     Ship loans  &       & Mortgage loans
     Senior MBS & Public Sector loans
     Senior MBS &       & Mortgage Loans  \\
         Geographical scope of cover assets  & Domestic, EEA, CH & Domestic, EEA, CH &       & Domestic (France Only) & Domestic  & Flexible  & Flexible  &       & Domestic, EEA, CH,          USA, Canada, Japan  &       & EEA, CH &       & Domestic and EEA &       & EEA   & EEA   &       & EEA \\
         Regulator CB specific disclosure requirements to public & Not mandatory  & Not mandatory  &       & Mandatory & Mandatory & Mandatory & Mandatory &       & Mandatory &       & Not mandatory  &       & Mandatory &       & Not mandatory  & Not mandatory  &       & Mandatory \\
         \bottomrule
     \end{longtable}%
     \end{landscape}
     \end{document}
```

There are some multiple columns as well. The desired form of table is given below:

[image]

Comment: You have 13 columns but your preamble declares only 3. Then, you have some `\multicolumn{19}{l}{...}`. Start by declaring the correct number of columns.

Comment: @EricDomenjoud I could not find where I have declared 3 in my preamble. Can you please specify. Mainly there are there 13 columns with text. But I want a space between the Main headings text. See the top row of desired table. To obtain this space I added additional blank columns in excel that make total 19. Please check the edited codes.

Comment: Ok. I understand where your 19 columns come from but your preamble is `{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7cm}}` which declares 3 columns, one aligned left, and two in paragraph mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space you are looking after is produced by the *trim* argument of `\cmidrule`, e.g. `\cmidrule(lr){2-3}`.  Please consult the documentation of the packages used here to get an understanding of what is happening.  Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,textheight=20cm}

\usepackage{booktabs,ragged2e,ltxtable,pdflscape,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{lt.tab}
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}p{3cm}*{12}{>{\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight}X}@{}}
  \caption{Structure}\label{tab:str}\\
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Main 1}}
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Main 2}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Main 3}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Main 4}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Main 5}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Main 6}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Main 7}} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-8}%
  \cmidrule(lr){9-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-10}\cmidrule(lr){11-12}\cmidrule(l){13-13}
  %
  & Text 1a & Text 1b & Text 2a & Text 2b & Text 2c & Text 2d
  & Text 3a & Text 4a & Text 5a & Text 6a & Text 6b & Text 7a \\
  %
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{13}{@{}l}{\textbf{Structure}} \\
  \midrule
  Issuer & Licensed UCI  & Licensed UCI & Specialised Credit Institution
  & Specialised Credit Institution  & Specialised Credit Institution
  & Specialised Credit Institution  & Licensed UCI & UCI
  & Licensed UCI  &  UCI, Specialised Credit Institution
  & UCI, Specialised Credit Institution & UCI, Specialised Credit Institution
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
  \footnotesize
  \LTXtable{20cm}{lt.tab}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

> [image]